# Get element attribute inside declaration - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This piece of javacsript code (using jquery.treeview and jquery.cookie plugins) produces cookies named "tree_state_undefined".

I'm really not much into javascript, so anyone can tell me, how to get IDs of individual ul.tree elements in initialization?

thanks very much

```
$("ul.tree").treeview({
        collapsed: true,
        animated: "medium",
        control:"#controller_" + $(this).attr('id'),
        persist: "cookie",
        cookieId: "tree_state_" + $(this).attr('id')
    });
```

for the record, it's this plugin:

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-treeview/blob/master/jquery.treeview.js

Comment: Isn't `$(this).attr('id')` giving you the *IDs of individual ul.tree elements* ?

Comment: no, using firefox debugger, I've found, $(this) points to <body> element :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try as:

```
$("ul.tree").each(function() {
    var $ul = $(this);
    $ul.treeview({
        collapsed: true,
        animated: "medium",
        control:"#controller_" + $ul.attr('id'),
        persist: "cookie",
        cookieId: "tree_state_" + $ul.attr('id')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At the point in which you are running the code, the value of the `this` variable is likely to be the `window`, or, for some reason we can't see from the code you posted, the `body` element.

The `this` value changes according to how a function is invoked, see [this section on Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this) for more details. In your case, I suspect that if this code is run globally, or inside a `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` block, `this` will refer to the `window`/`document`.

Thus when you try to do `$(this).attr('id')`, it is trying to get the `id` attribute of the body, which is undefined. Then you concatenate that to a string, which is why you get a cookie called "tree_state_undefined".

Comment: yes, this was exactly the case - $(this) refered to the body element inside the functions...